# Access variable outside $.each LOOP

Tags: jquery, each

How can I access appraisalAddress outside the $.each loop so that is is available within the showMap function? Is this possible? I am running this code in a appery.io service execution where "data" at the top level is an array of objects

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'xyz';

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
.setView([32.7833333, -96.8], 13);


function geocodeAppraisals() {

var appraisalAddress = 'Dallas';

$.each(data, function(i, item) {

    appraisalAddress = item.PropertyAddress + " " + item.PropertyCity + " " + item.PropertyState + " " + item.PropertyZipCode;

    console.log(appraisalAddress);

    var geocoder = L.mapbox.geocoder('mapbox.places-v1');
    geocoder.query(appraisalAddress, showMap);

});


function showMap(err, data) {
    console.log('showMap');
    console.log('appraisalAddress', appraisalAddress); // always shows the same address... the last item in $.each
    if (err) throw err;
    if (data.lbounds) {
        map.fitBounds(data.lbounds);

    } else if (data.latlng) {
        var marker = L.marker([data.latlng[0], data.latlng[1]], {
            icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                'marker-size': 'small',
                //'marker-symbol': 'bus',
                'marker-color': '#fa0'
            }),
            clickable: true,
            draggable: false,
            keyboard: true,
            title: appraisalAddress,
            alt: appraisalAddress,
            zIndexOffset: 0,
            opacity: 1.0,
            riseOnHover: false,
            riseOffset: 250
        }).addTo(map);

        map.setView([data.latlng[0], data.latlng[1]], 13);

    }
}
}

geocodeAppraisals();
```

Comment: You should pass it into the `showMap` function

Comment: That was one of the first things i tried. Not sure how as the obvious does not work. But then again I am new to JS.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `appraisalAddress` is scoped within the `geocodeAppraisals` function, which is why the function `showMap` can't get to its value.

Have you tried defining `appraisalAddress` outside of the function bodies? that should make it available to all of your functions.